# Python tkinter create multi language software

Tags: python, tkinter, multilingual

I am working on my own text editor. I want my text editor to be in English and in Spanish. How can I let the user choose between the two languages and that it updates Immediately?

Comment: This question is too broad, please show what you have tried. What is exactly your issue? One of the possibility for translating a software is to use [gettext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html)  and there are many examples on the Internet.

Comment: If you would read my question you would understand what I mean

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean, this was just a way of saying that your question does not show enough research effort. StackOverflow is not meant to be a code writing service and I don't want to write all the code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way you can do it. code 2 function for your program to change the language of every single label you have. changing name of the title (as shown below), name of buttons, menus, and so on.

```
import tkinter as Tk


def change_language_eng():
    root.title('Program')
    menuButton.config(text='Menu')


def change_language_spa():
    root.title('Programa')
    menuButton.config(text='Menú')

    
root = Tk.Tk()
root.title('Program')
menuButton = Tk.Button(root, text='Menu')
engButton = Tk.Button(root, text='English', command=change_language_eng)
spaButton = Tk.Button(root, text='Spanish', command=change_language_spa)
menuButton.grid(row=0, column=0)
engButton.grid(row=1, column=0)
spaButton.grid(row=2, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```